# How to stop chrome from upgrading websockets from WS to WSS when the websocket object is created on an HTTPS page

Tags: javascript, http, websocket, https

I made a real browser port of minecraft here that is multiplayer only, it is based on websockets.

https://g.eags.us/eaglercraft/

I want the game on this page to be able to connect to servers using both the WS and WSS websocket protocol, so buying web SSL certificates is not mandatory for the people who are just trying to set up small private servers to use to play this game on from school computers or something. Both my origin server and cloudflare are currently configured to be strictly HTTPS only and you cannot normally initialize an insecure WS websocket from a secure HTTPS page, meaning anyone trying to play the game on their own server off of my 'official' link will need an SSL certificate and a WSS URI.

I have added the `content-security-policy: upgrade-insecure-requests` header to the link I posted above. I am under the impression that this enables regular insecure HTTP/WS connections to be made on the page even if the page was loaded via HTTPS but it doesn't appear to work. When I create a WebSocket object in chrome devtools console of this page and tried connecting it to a WS URI, the network tab shows that the actual request used by the object had the WS in the URI replaced with WSS even though the URI I typed was WS.

How do I disable all this behavior for this specific page and just perform the websocket request as-is

Comment: Note that you don't have to pay for SSL certificates these days. Services like [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) provide them for free.

Comment: `content-security-policy: upgrade-insecure-requests` announces that the requestor supports secure connections and requests that the connection be upgraded. See [Upgrade-Insecure-Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Upgrade-Insecure-Requests)

Comment: You cannot make a `ws:` connection from an `https:` page. This would make a secure page insecure so browsers block it. There are configurations in the browser to change this behavior but it is not recommended as it weakens security. See [Allowing insecure WebSocket connections](https://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20210528-AllowingInsecureWebsocketConnections.html)

Comment: @Ouroborus that doesn't really help me, you posted the wrong MDN link the link you posted is for an actual header that is also named `upgrade-insecure-requests`. I am talking about a header named `content-security-policy` which has `upgrade-insecure-requests` as a possible argument

Comment: @Ouroborus and I am fully aware of the reasons why the browser is set not to do this by default I get it I do not need people telling me why doing this is bad practice I am simply asking for someone to post me a real unbiased direct answer to my question and nothing else

Comment: The answer is clear: You would need to make your site available under both HTTP and HTTPS. Then use WS with HTTP and WSS with HTTPS. There's not enough information in your question to be able to help with making those configuration changes.

Comment: Regarding `content-security-policy: upgrade-insecure-requests`, apologies for my error. I'm pretty sure this only applies to HTTP/HTTPS. The spec talks about in this context and I'm unable to find anything that mentions it in the context of WS/WSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misinterpreted the header's behavior. It was working as advertised, upgrading the URI from WS to WSS. I initially interpreted it as a header that applies a permission override for the browser to just treat all socket URIs as if they had already been upgraded to WSS without actually upgrading the underlying URIs and requests.

Apologies for my 3:00 AM confusion, see the [MDN Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests) for more clarification